# how to return an int array in function

Tags: arrays, search, return

```
public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        
        for(int i = 0;i < nums.length;i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < nums.length;j++) {
                if(i != j && nums[i] + nums[j] == target) {
                    int[] arr = new int[] {i,j};
                    return arr[];
                }
            }
            
        }
        
    }
```

The part (**return arr[];**) gives me an error. Can you explain to me why? Thanks.

Comment: Class<arr[]> cannot be resolved to a type  ---- its the error

Answer (score 0):

When you declare an array of integers, you use the syntax

```
int[] arr;
```

For this point onward the array (or rather, a pointer to the array) can be accessed via `arr` and the n-th element of your array, if it exists, can be accessed via `arr[n-1]`. The syntax `arr[]` is invalid and would be superfluous since `are` is already an array. Try returning just `arr`

The error seemingly occurs because you are trying to return a array whose elements are supposed to be of type `arr`. Such a class is not defined and even if it was, such an array has not yet been declared.